# How can I got from Camera 640*X large picture back?

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, image-scaling

Hi I now call the camera intent whit argument where to place the image, like this:

```
imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "tmpPic.jpg"));
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
```

and i retrieve the image on activity result like this:

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/tmpPic.jpg";
                if (yourSelectedImage != null)
                    yourSelectedImage.recycle();
                yourSelectedImage = null;

                final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
                options.inSampleSize = 1;
                // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
                break;
```

but before the break at line `yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);` it fall for out of memory exception. I know that sample size is the way to get smaller images, but is that a way that i can specify that I wanna have 640*X big Bitmap at the and? Or how can I at least track that the incoming image is too big and i should use a sample size?

Comment: Strange that you're getting the OOM, I've used basically identical code without any problem.  Why are you calling `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);` twice?

Comment: To know the bounds of the image, I hoped it ti a way to set sample size